# Is it possible to use Aggregate function in a Select statment without using Group By clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, aggregate-functions

So far I have written Aggregate function followed by Group By clause to find the values based on SUM, AVG and other Aggregate functions. I have a bit confusion in the Group By clause.
When we use Aggregate functions what are the columns I need to specify in the Group By clause.
Otherwise Is there any way to use Aggregate functions without using Group By clause.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

All columns in the SELECT clause that do not have an aggregate need to be in the GROUP BY

Good:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

Also good:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col5, col6
```

No other columns = no GROUP BY needed

```
SELECT MAX(col4)
...
```

Won't work:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Pointless:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
```

Having an aggregate (MAX etc) with other columns without a GROUP BY makes no sense because the query becomes ambiguous.

Comment: So In the Group By Clause, we need to specify all the Columns what we have selected and we may of may not include the aggregate Column. This is what you have specified. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, but you shouldn't include the aggregate column. That also makes no sense

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to just group by the row ID for a given table -- discovered with trial and error in PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: @sventechie: PG honours the SQL standard more than others, which says (I think!) that `GROUP BY <primary key>` should be the same as `GROUP BY <primary key>, <nonkey column1>, <nonkey column2> `. That is, the PK is unique already so nonkey columns can be ignored

Comment: `select student_id, max(score) from students` this wont work as aggregate function used without group by and has a column not in group-by selected in query. `select max(score) from students` this will work without group by as no column not in group-by is selected. to give same result as 1st query, you can use subquery `select student_id, (select max(score) from students) as max_score from students`, this will work. Not going into efficiency of query but just stating what will work and what will not.

Answer (score 35):

You can use Select AGG() OVER() in TSQL

```
SELECT *,
SUM(Value) OVER()
FROM Table
```

There are other options for Over such as Partition By if you want to group:

```
SELECT *,
SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION By ParentId)
FROM Table
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: +1 Note for GROUP BY will collapse rows to the grouping, PARTITION BY will keep all rows. Still useful though

Comment: Feels super hacky, but it worked for my case.  Also seemed to not be overly optimized, as my query slowed down significantly.

Comment: This is the best answer for the spirit of the question.

Comment: Note: we call this a *window function*

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can use an aggregate without GROUP BY:

```
SELECT SUM(col) FROM tbl;
```

This will return one row only - the sum of the column "col" for all rows in tbl (excluding nulls).

Answer (score 3):

You must group by columns that do *not* have aggregate functions on them.

You may avoid a group by clause if *all* columns selected have aggregate functions applied.

Answer (score 3):

The Columns which are not present in the Aggregate function should come on group by clause:

```
Select 
Min(col1), 
Avg(col2), 
sum(col3) 
from table
```

then we do not required group by clause, But if there is some column which are not present in the  Aggregate function then you must use group by  for that column.

```
Select 
col1, 
col2, 
sum(col3) 
from  table 
group by col1,col2
```

then we have to use the group by for the column col1 and col2

Answer (score 1):

You omit columns from the SELECT inside aggregate functions, all other columns should exist in GROUP BY clause seperated by comma.

You can have query with aggregates and no group by, as long as you have ONLY aggregate values in the SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, without aggregate functions we can use group by column but it will be a distinct function.

```
select <column name> from <table name> group by <column name>
```

Given the table `EMP`:

```
select * from EMP
```

That outputs:

```
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839
```

Adding a `group by`

```
select job from EMP group by job
```

Outputs:

```
CLERK
SALESMAN
MANAGER
```