# MYSQL QUERY sum from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey there I am having a bit of trouble with the following Mysql query, how can I calculate the SUMS(which are calculating points, the 5th and 6th sum in the query) from the team_stats table not the driver_stats table but also with the same condition as now for where team_id = 3. All i need is too swap those calculations from the driver_stats table to the team_stats table, the problem I am having is when I have tryed doing it, the calculations are way to high like it is not doing them just for where team_id = '3' or whatever number.

Any help would be great thanks.

```
SELECT       t.teamname,
             t.value,
             SUM(IF(qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
             SUM(IF(race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
             SUM(IF(race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
             SUM(overtakes) AS overtakes,
             SUM(CASE
               WHEN s.track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) THEN
                 points
               ELSE
                 0
             End) AS lastracepoints,

             # CHANGE THIS SUM AND THE SUM ABOVE TO CALCULATE
             # the points column in the tale named TEAM_STATS
             # but with the same restrictions as now,
             # only where team_id = 3
             SUM(points) AS points 

FROM         driver_stats s
  LEFT JOIN  drivers d
  ON         d.drivers_id = s.drivers_id
  LEFT JOIN  teams t
  ON         d.team_id = t.team_id
WHERE        d.team_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can let you use aggregates (sum) without defining the group by clause in special cases, but it is not typical and won't work for you.

[Is it possible to use Aggregate function in a Select statment without using Group By clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467216/is-it-possible-to-use-aggregate-function-in-a-select-statment-without-using-grou)

I haven't tested this by try:

```
SELECT       t.teamname,
             t.value,
             SUM(IF(qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
             SUM(IF(race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
             SUM(IF(race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
             SUM(overtakes) AS overtakes,
             SUM(CASE
               WHEN s.track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) THEN
                 points
               ELSE
                 0
             End) AS lastracepoints,
             SUM(points) AS points 

FROM         drivers d
  INNER JOIN  driver_stats s
  ON         d.drivers_id = s.drivers_id
  AND         d.team_id = 3
  LEFT JOIN  teams t
  ON         d.team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY
    teamname,
    `value`
```